# How to get ip information of arouter/AP with ESP8266

Tags: esp8266

i, I would like to get ip number, DHCP ip range subnet mask information of an external AP/router autonomusly through the ESP8266 sketch, so the ESP8266 code can determine a suitable static ip range to configure. Any example code or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

All you can do is get what DHCP gives you.

1. Connect to the AP
2. Use DHCP to get an IP address
3. Store the IP, netmask and gateway in variables
4. Use the netmask to determine the "fixed" bits in the IP address.
5. Replace the "unfixed" bits of the IP with your own chosen IP portion
6. Re-set the IP information with your static information.

What you *cannot* do is determine what the DHCP *range* is. Only the router knows that, and it doesn't broadcast it.

The proper way of handling it, though, is to get the router to provide a fixed DHCP IP address for the MAC address the ESP8266 has. Most routers have this functionality available.

Comment: Thank you for your response Majenko. WHat I want to do is to handle all configuration for connecting to the network by ESP 8266 or an Android app. User should only need to select the AP and enter password. No other configuration should be needed from user. I need to make sure that the ip that I pick does not conflict wit already assigned dynamic or static ip addresses. For example if I configured a router for a specific IP with a MAC address, I cannot reconfigure same IP for another MAC address unless I reset the router to factory settings.

Comment: May be I can use the DHCP assigned ip as static IP, I would like to try if it works.